# No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_alignParentEnd' in package 'android' activity_post.xml /DispatchActivity/res/layout line 23

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

Got this error while trying to run https://github.com/ParsePlatform/AnyWall in Eclipse

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_alignParentEnd' in package 'android'  activity_post.xml   /DispatchActivity/res/layout    line 23 Android AAPT Problem

Comment: http://pastebin.com/CAwJan9A

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What target platform do you use?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#layout_alignParentEnd

Attribute `layout_alignParentEnd` was added in API level 17, so it should not work on earlier APIs. Try to reconfigure the project for appropriate API level.